# How to send email with "holiday order" confirmation?

Tags: laravel

How can I prepare code to send email with confirmaton. We have a holiday module and employees can order a holiday directly from system. Next I see holiday order in list to confirm. After my confirmation holiday is confirmed.

Where I have to put this code for receive email with info that new holiday is ordered?

Thanks.
Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, please provide some code of what you have tried so far and we will help to debug your problem. If you are looking for someone to come up with a full solution for you then I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not the place for this.

Comment: I have this line:
`use App\Mail\NewHoliday;`

Comment: I have all controllers, all classes but I don't know exactly where I have tu put line with sending email.

Comment: `public function create(Request $request)`
`$user = auth()->user();`

Comment: `        if ($user->hasRole('manager')) {
            $user = User::find($request->userId);
            if ($request->id && !empty($request->id)) {
                $absence = Absence::where('id', $request->id)->first();
                $absence->type_id = $request->absenceId;
                $absence->info = $request->info;`

Comment: `$absence->user_id = $request->userId;
                $absence->begin = new \Carbon\Carbon($request->startDate);
                $absence->end = new \Carbon\Carbon($request->endDate);
                $absence->save();`

Comment: `} else {
                $absence = new \App\Absence();
                $absence->type_id = $request->absenceId;
                $absence->status_id = 3;
                $absence->info = $request->info;`

Comment: `$absence->user_id = $request->userId;
                $absence->begin = new \Carbon\Carbon($request->startDate);
                $absence->end = new \Carbon\Carbon($request->endDate);
                $user->absences()->create($absence->toArray());
                return $absence->id;
            }
        }`

Comment: `if ($user->hasRole('employee')) {
            $user = auth()->user();
            $absence = new \App\Absence();
            $absence->type_id = 1;
            $absence->status_id = 3;`

Comment: `$absence->begin = $request->startDate;
            $absence->end = $request->endDate;
            $absence = $user->absences()->create($absence->toArray());

            return $absence->id;
        }

 
    }`

Comment: It is the code. It works but where I have to put sending email line?

Comment: @martin.please add that code in question.its bit difficult to read in comment section

Answer (score 0):

This logic should be put wherever you confirm holidays. For example:

Let's say, for example, you have confirm holiday method in your controller. At the end of that logic, you can call your `NewHoliday` class:

```
public function confirmHoliday(){
    //Your logic of confirming holiday
    Mail::to($user)->send(new NewHoliday($parameters));
}
```

Comment: Email must be send to administrator, not to user.

Comment: There are  in `NewHoliday`:

`public function __construct($absence)
    {
        $this->subject('Neue Urlaubsantrag: '.$absence->user->name);
        $this->absence = $absence;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $absence = $this->absence;
        return $this->view('email.new-holiday',compact('absence'));`

Comment: This was just an example, you can pass whatever parameter you want to your   `NewHoliday `  class. Since I don't see your controller code, I just placed this code  to point you to the right direction.